# How can I draw a tailor-made contour plot?

Tags: plotting

Given the following code:

```
ClearAll[a, sector, cap, lab, va, fd, μ, γ, outputS, priceS, gdpS];
a = 
  {{58/493, 75/831, 98/900}, 
   {123/493, 342/831, 198/900}, 
   {178/493, 215/831, 343/900}} // N}
sector = 3;
cap = {110/493, 150/831, 200/900};
lab = {24/493, 49/831, 61/900};  
va = cap + lab;
fd = {262/493, 168/831, 164/900};  
μ = {0.05, 0.00, 0.00};
γ = {0.15, 0.00, 0.00};  
outputS = (Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sector] - (1 + γ)*a].fd)
priceS = (valueAdded.Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sector] - (1 + μ)*a])
gdpS = priceS.outputS
```

Note that I have **two-parameter vectors** `μ` and `γ` (taking values between 0 and 1) but I only change **one element from each vector** (in this example, the first element from each vector), while keeping the rest of the parameters unchanged. How can I construct:

```
ContourPlot[gdpS == 1.5, {μ, ...}, {γ, ...}]
```

for a given value of `gdpS = 1.5`, while changing only `two elements` from `two-parameter vectors`.

Comment: I am missing something: At the moment, `gdpS` only depends on the parameter `a`, which is not defined, but it does not depend on $\mu$ or $\gamma$. You could re-define `outputS` and `priceS` to be functions of $\mu$ and $\gamma$, though.

Comment: @MarcoB: Sorry. I noticed something weird in my post. I will edit it immediately.

Comment: @MarcoB: Thanks for the code. `a` is a given matrix. I will try your answer with this matrix. I hope it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redefine your `outputS`, `priceS`, `gdpS` functions to explicitly depend on `μ` and `γ`:

```
ClearAll[outputSfunction, priceSfunction, gdpSfunction]
outputSfunction[γ_] := (Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sector] - (1 + γ)*a].fd)
priceSfunction[μ_] := (valueAdded.Inverse[IdentityMatrix[sector] - (1 + μ)*a])
gdpSfunction[μ_, γ_] := priceSfunction[μ].outputSfunction[γ]
```

Then, after assigning an arbitrary value to a that would allow the function to attain the value of $1.5$, since one was not provided:

```
Block[{a = 0.4},
 ContourPlot[
   gdpSfunction[{firstMu, 0, 0}, {firstGamma, 0, 0}],
   {firstMu, 0, 1}, {firstGamma, 0, 1},
   Contours -> {1.5}
 ]
]
```

[image: contour plot]

Comment: Your answer works fine by simply replacing `a` with a matrix (3,3). I simply inserted matrix `a` into `Block[{a=matrix data},...]`. thank you very much.

Comment: @Tugrul Great! Glad to hear that.

Comment: Can we have a ContourPlot in 3D where any two elements from `[Mu]` and one element from `[Gamma]` change? Analogous to `{x,y,z}` plane, I want to have a plane with  `{mu1, mu2, gamma1}` where `gamma1` is the surface (height).

Comment: @Tugrul `ContourPlot3D` would probably work, with the appropriate modifications. It may be trying to convey too much information in one plot though.